# Outline material for Cycles and EEVEE?

Tags: materials

I want to have a material that can make the outline of the mesh—whatever its shape and whatever the angle—glow. (This is not dissimilar to the freestyle setting.) What material node setup can I use to achieve this effect??

Comment: Have you tried using the Fresnel node?

Comment: Yes. The fresnel node often effects areas other than the outline, so I don’t think it’s the right solution.

Comment: Does this apporach work for you? https://www.blendernation.com/2020/02/28/daily-blender-tip-inverted-hull-toon-outline/